# QPushButton get color

Tags: python, button, pyqt

In this function I am trying to get the **bgColor** of the button that triggers it, so the background color can be set to its default color again.

```
def clickColor(button, color):
    bgColor = button.palette().color(QPalette.Background)
    button.setStyleSheet("background-color: %s" % color)
    QTimer.singleShot(300, lambda: unClickColor(button, bgColor))

def unClickColor(button, beforeColor):
    button.setStyleSheet("background-color: %s" % bgColor)
```

It gives the following error message:

```
Could not parse stylesheet of object 0x234ba20
```

Printing the bgColor variable gives:

```
<PyQt5.QtGui.QColor object at 0x7f28792c8358>
```

Comment: always put in question full error message (Traceback). There are other usefull information, ie. which line makes problem.

Comment: BTW: `bgColor` is local variable which exists only in `clickColor` and you use it in `unClickColor` - you should use `beforeColor`.

Comment: And you need to use `bgColor.name()` to convert the `QColor` to a string in RGB format (e.g. "#FF0000").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Must use color name() method and the color parameter name in unclick function:

```
def unClickColor(button, beforeColor):
    button.setStyleSheet("background-color: %s" % beforeColor.name())
```

Tested and works.